# How to Check Jtable Values in IF Condition With For Loop

Tags: java, swing, loops

My code only works for the 1st row. I want to add a row if it is not in the JTable. `Class_assing_tb` is my JTable.

I want to add values, which I get from JCombobox, to JTable when I click "Add Item" button. It can only input a maximum of 4 items. I want to do it like this, if I add an item that is already in the JTable I want to give a message "Denied" else add the item to JTable.

```
int count = Class_assing_tb.getRowCount();
if (count == 0) {
    addrow(); //this is to Command For Add new Row
} else if (count == 4) {
    System.out.println("maximum Row Count");
    // msg ****** Maximum Classes
} else {
    int a = Class_assing_tb.getRowCount();
    DefaultTableModel tm2 = (DefaultTableModel) Class_assing_tb.getModel();
    loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        //System.out.println("Row Count is" + a);
        // System.out.println("Sttate is"+i);
        if (tm2.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(mng_stu_classatnd.getSelectedItem()) & tm2.getValueAt(i, 2).equals(mng_stu_batch.getSelectedItem()) & tm2.getValueAt(i, 3).equals(mng_stu_type.getSelectedItem())) {
            System.out.println("Denied");
            break loop;
        } else {
            addrow();//this is to Command For Add new Row
            // continue loop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem and your code in greater detail.

Comment: I want to Add Values which is Get from Jcombobox to Jtable When i clicked Add Item button , It Can Be Input Only maximum 4 items , I want to Do like this , if I add Already Added item in Jtable I want to Give A message "Denied" Else Add Item to jtable

Comment: _"It can only input a maximum of 4 items"_ - What _exactly_ is an _"Item"_? Is it a complete row? Is it just one cell in a row? How many cells does each row have?

Comment: Unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

//Global Declaration

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
```

//Display only header on form load

```
//create header for the table
header = new Vector<String>();
header.add("Column"); 
model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
table = new JTable(model);
```

//in actionPerformed()

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource()==add){
    int count=table.getRowCount();
    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(table.getValueAt(i,0).equals(jComboBox.getSelectedItem())){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null,"Duplicate...");
           return;
    }
    }

    if(count==4){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null,"Maximum Limit is crossed...");
    }else{
     Object d= jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
     model.addRow(d);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should put more explanation into your answer. Though your answer may work, it doesn't teach the reader what they are doing wrong and how it was corrected. Or if you took a completely different approach from the OP, still explain what you're doing in your code. It makes for a much better answer :)

Comment: @peeskillet OK Thank you. I got, what you want to say. Next time I will take care about the explanation part also.